# client event not firing when texbox value changes

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have a `TextBox` that is the target control ID of a Ajax calendar extender.

When I select a different date in the Ajax calendar, the `TextBox` gets populated with the date but the client-side change event is not fired for the `TextBox`.

The change event does not fire even when the `TextBox` is empty at the time of selecting the date.

aspx code below

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtPaymentDate" runat="server" MaxLength="10">`
`</asp:TextBox>`

`<asp:ImageButton SkinID="Calendar" ID="imgPaydtPopup" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"/>`

`<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="cmvPaymentDate" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtPaymentDate" ForeColor="Red">`
`</asp:CompareValidator>`

`<ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calPaymentDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtPaymentDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgPaydtPopup" PopupPosition="BottomLeft">`
`</ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender>`

Comment: Can you post some sample code or create a jsfiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: post your `.aspx` code

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onclientdateselectionchanged` property for Calendar control and do what you want in the Javascript function that is called on Calender change.

```
<ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calPaymentDate" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtPaymentDate"
    onclientdateselectionchanged="yourJavascriptFunction" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgPaydtPopup" PopupPosition="BottomLeft">
</ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: Moshtaf : In the javascript function the text box always shows current selected date value. I don't have a previous value to compare with.

Comment: As i understand, you need to do some work on TextBox's value is changed and try to do that using client-side change event that associated with that textbox, as you say this event is not fired on data changes, but the `onclientdateselectionchanged` is fired on every data change, so you can using this.

Answer (score 0):

The onchange event of the textbox worked for me!!

here is the code

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtCancelDate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" onchange="TxtDateChanged()">`
`</asp:TextBox>`